# Sequelize Group By Returns Not All Attributes

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a query to returns everything that a device has.

Currently my query is:

```
var getHardwareData = function() {
    return Device.findAll({
        where: {
            ownerId: req.account.id
        },
        attributes: [
            '"hardwareName"',
            [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', '*'), 'count'],
        ],
        group: '"hardwareName"',
    }).then(function(devices) {
        return devices;
    });
};
```

I want to have hardwareName and the count of it. Currently it returns `count: 1` and only it.

Comment: You don't need to quote hardwareName in the attributes `'hardwareName'` should work fine

What does the SQL query look like?

Comment: Sequelize has a bug related to camel case column names in group attribute. @JanAagaardMeier

Comment: Alright, I just thought that the column would be double quoted in the attributes. Can you post the sql?